# Does Redshift SVV_TABLE_INFO size field include deleted but not vacuumed data?

Tags: amazon-redshift

According to [redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html), SVV_TABLE_INFO.tbl_rows field *includes rows marked for deletion, but not yet vacuumed*. But SVV_TABLE_INFO.size field is only described as *Size of the table, in 1 MB data blocks*. I would like to get the data before and after running manual vacuum command to determine the effectiveness of vacuuming on the table. Therefore clarification is needed.

Comment: I wonder manual vacuuming is still necessary for deletes, starting Dec 2018 `VACUUM DELETE` runs automatically.    https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-redshift-automatic-vacuum/

Comment: Auto vacuum doesn't seem working effectively as expected. I am comparing auto-vacuum result with manual vacuum to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, size includes `deleted` records `size` as well till `Vacuum` happens.

Steps to prove my point.

```
# select table_id,size from SVV_TABLE_INFO where table_id='358723';
 table_id |  size
----------+------
   358723 |   52
(1 row)
```

Now `Delete` records.

```
delete from example_table where c_name='12';
DELETE 200009
```

Now, run again the

```
select table_id,size from SVV_TABLE_INFO where table_id='358723';
 table_id |  size
----------+------
   358723 |   52
(1 row)
```

Now, run the `vacuum`.

```
vacuum delete only example_table;

select table_id,'table',size from SVV_TABLE_INFO where table_id='358723';
 table_id | size
----------+------
   358723 |   44
(1 row)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for verifying. Size is in MB so I assume your deleted row is as big as 8mb?